# Can't reference System.xml in Uno

Tags: xamarin, uno-platform

In VS 2019, a compiling Uno project and minimal UI.  I'm trying to deserialize some XML.
This is trivial in the Windows world:  Just reference it with "using System.Xml.Serialization;" and add "System.XML" to your references in your project.  It all just works.
In Uno, the projects don't have a references section.  And "Add Reference" off of the Shared Project gives, literally, not figuratively but literally, no choices.  Can't do a damned thing.
But it can't resolve the attributes (e.g. [XmlAttribute("...")], [XmlRoot("...")])
What's the fix?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add references to a Shared Project because it doesn't compile by itself. It's just a list of files which get included in any project that references it. You need to add the required references to those projects that are referencing the shared project (ie `MyUnoApp.Droid`, `MyUnoApp.UWP`, `MyUnoApp.WASM` etc.)

Specifically in the case of `System.Xml.Serialization`, it seems to be available off the bat for most platforms without having to add extra references. In some, eg macOS, it is not, but you can add `System.Xml` to those 'head' projects in the normal manner you describe.

Comment: Yeah, it's necessary.  But perhaps because I'm doing MacOS also.  Well, attempting to.  But you've got the crux of it...

Comment: Yes, I see that too - I didn't check macOS initially. But 'Add reference' on the macOS head will work. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to stem with Uno's incomplete macOS support.  If *any* project (platform) can't resolve a reference, the entire solution breaks, and System.Xml / System.Xml.Serialization are not implicitly provided by Uno, so the functionality broke.

The solution is to explicitly add the reference to the .macOS project. This enabled all of them.